# Finding a grouping algorithm

Tags: algorithm

The question is like this:

A object **A** has there elements 1,2,3, **B** has three, **C** has four：

A : 1,2,3
B : 1,2
C : 3,4,5

The elements are all integers and they are unique in within every object.  A group means a set of numbers of the elements, such as {1,2}, {3,4}, {3,4,5}.   Then define the weight of a object is the num of its elements or groups.

The aim is to find a **grouping algorithm** of all the elements to get the minimum weight of all the objects.

For example, the minimum weight is:

The best groups are {1,2} {4,5}

A : {1,2}, 3 => 2
B : {1,2}   => 1
C : 3, {4,5} => 2

The minimum weight is 5 = 2 + 1 + 2
**Attention :** each element can only in one group.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: list all the possible groups and calculate the Weight, then find the minmum. but there are 1000+ interges and 500+ objects, it has high time complexity.

Comment: there is a mistake. the minWeight is 4, when {3,4,5} is a group, the weight of C is 1.

Comment: I think there should be another constraint that two groups can not have any common element. Otherwise minimum weight always will be equal to #Objects

Comment: yes,"each element can only be in one group".